# Required and formSubmit() complications

Tags: html, required

i have form and my sumbit button is out of this form(on a right side of my website - reservation button) so i made formSubmit() to call this form with id. I decided to to use html5 and required because user must define their info like name,email ...

This is code:

```
<script>
    function formSubmit()
     {

     document.getElementById("reservation").submit();

     }
    </script>

    and my form

    <form method='post' action='mail.php' id='reservation' >
    <input required type='text' name='from' id='FadeMeIna' size='6'  />
    <input required type='text' name='to' id='FadeMeInb' size='6' />
    <input required type='text' name='email' id='formdetail'  value='' size='16'  />
    </form>

    this is my submit button in a new div 

    <p type="submit" style="display:none;" onclick="formSubmit();" /> <a href="#">Rezervovať</a></p>
```

My problem is with required it doesnt work i was looking for solutions but i didnt find anything

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

`Required` does work, as you can see on this jsfiddle that I've created with your form and a submit button:

http://jsfiddle.net/d3Y25/

So perhaps your problem is that you are bypassing the browser based checking of that field, and creating your own submit function with a script. So when the user presses the submit button it does what you've asked it to - submit the form via a script.

If you use the form based submit option you get to use the HTML5 required property as it was intended. If not I guess you need to check those fields are populated via JS before submitting.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that interactive form validation is only done on user interaction (press enter in an input or click on a submit button. You can not currently use the form api to achieve this. (But there is something coming called reportValidity. )

The good news is, HTML5 has something else for you the form content attribute.

```
<form method='post' action='mail.php' id='reservation' >
    <input required type='text' name='from' id='FadeMeIna' size='6'  />
    <input required type='text' name='to' id='FadeMeInb' size='6' />
    <input required type='email' name='email' id='formdetail'  value='' size='16'  />
</form>


<button type="submit" form="reservation" />Rezervovať</button>
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/trixta/fP72G/